# Confirmation email for newsletter signups drupal 7

Tags: emails

Is it possible to send a confirmation email when someone signs up to my newsletter. When the user signs up an email should be sent to his mail conforming his subscripition and to await more info. Is this possible through the webform?

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely possible.

1. Go to admin/content/webform
2. Click Edit for the webform you want to modify.
3. Click on the Webform tab
4. Click on the E-mails sub-tab
5. Add a new one.

Once in there you can set all of the options you need to send an email to the person signing up.